# How to use fluent style of coding in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium automation testing. One of my projects uses fluent style of selenium code. I am facing an issue with this pattern, my application behaves login differently, if it is a new user [login for the first time] the set of pages are different from normal login.

Eg:-

New User:

LoginPage -> Security Questions ->...-> final page.

Old user:

LoginPage -> Advertisement -> final page.

How to handle this situation in fluent style of coding.

Comment: Can you please give more explanation ? and Please also what do you mean by "fluent style of selenium code" ? What language you use ?

Comment: fluent is java only for selenium (at the moment)

Comment: We are using C#. We want to implement fluent style of coding.

Comment: You can implement your own version of fluent (if you do then put it on git as others might be interested too!) but the official version is Java only at this time.

Answer (score 1):

[Fluent](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/fluent-selenium)  grants you additional options for commands and usage in addition to those offered by Selenium Webdriver itself.  What this means is you can use the fluent options And those offered as standard in java/Webdriver.

Neither forces a particular work flow upon you for how application manages login(s).   As such you can just write your tests as you would normally.

For the sake of code practices I would suggest you create a shared library for your login functionality so the code can be reused across tests and avoid duplication.